# Retrieve value from JSON responce

Tags: android, json, parsing

I am writing an android application and currently i am getting a JSON reply:

```
{"Error":"User already exists"}
```

this is an example of the messages that i get returned

the part that i am after is : "User already exists" and i need to parse it.

The message is currently stored in a string so i would need to convert this to a JSONArray to then convert it to a JSONOject to then be able to call the getString().

what would be the best way to do this?

Comment: Almost like you said: I can't see an enclosing JSONArray, though. But if it's there, you proceed as you say. It's not _that_ complicated. Have a look at the Android JSON reference page.

Comment: that is my full json that is all i get returned

Comment: By your explanation I think you have already done that.There few alternatives also like Jackson,Gson etc

Answer (score 2):

this may Helps You

```
String Respones= "{\"Error\":\"User already exists\"}";
try {
        JSONObject jobj = new JSONObject(Respones);         
        String strError = jobj.getString("Error");              
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: If Responces is the string that holds the json message then it throws this exception:
Value User already exists at Error of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject

Comment: check your Response is as Given or any Changes in Response

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do it directly with JSONTokener and JSONObject if you want ot use default andoid tools.

If you want better, look into the Jackson lib, it's very powerful, open source, kind of standard:

[Android JSON Jackson Tutorial](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11132891/android-json-jackson-tutorial)

Answer (score -1):

Try this code

```
JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(ResponseString);

for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

String result = jsonObject.getString("Error").toString().trim();

}
```